# Significance of exact solutions to differential equations

Tags: schroedinger-equation, differential-equations

What is the importance of finding new exact solutions to partial differential equations? I kindly need someone to convince me, since my PhD will be on that.

Comment: You should ask your thesis advisor.

Comment: Not all questions could be asked to advisor that is why l am sharing here.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an analytical/exact (in contrast to some say "discretized" or similar numerical) solution, interpretation of the coefficients in this solution is much more straightforward than tackling a generic numerical solution. These coefficients of the exact solution can also be fitted to experiments to gain an understanding in that context.

An analytical solution typically is also a more tractable than a more generic numerical one (fewer parameters), and this can allow for building more complex models on top of it (which can quickly become unfeasible, if one had to build a model out of many already complicated numerical solutions). Example: exact quantum mechanical solution of the harmonic oscillator, where the exact eigenvalues (with mathematically simple form) of the modes can be employed to model what happens if you have many modes to occupy (e.g. phonons in a solid). This would be much more complicated if one would not have the understanding of the simple analytical structure of the spectrum.

Exactly solvable models had and have importance in gaining deeper understanding in a field at a very general (i.e. deep) level.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply